# External monitor showing greenish shadow

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, display

I've got a macbook pro 2011 and am using a mini-display to dvi adapter to hook up a ViewSonic monitor (Viewsonic VX2450WM-LED 24-Inch).  Problem is this greenish shadow showing up for certain hues of white, I'm not sure what it is or how to fix it.

I've tried multiple mini display to dvi adapters and DVI cables with no change.  As far as I know DVI is the best I can do on this monitor, and I've tried all the display color settings possible (including calibrating) and nothing gets rid of the hue.
Any idea what causes this?

[image]

Comment: It looks like a form of ghosting, so it would be useful to determine if it appears only in certain areas of the screen or all over.  Open windows of different sizes and see if the shape of the color changes is specific to certain window in a certain position.  Also if possible try a different monitor to see if the issue occurs as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response Stu.
It appears throughout the entire screen, when that particular shade of off-white is displayed.  
The issue doesn't happen using the same cables/computer with a different display (Acer lcd).

Comment: It's getting worse, must be a faulty monitor.  I'm in the process of contacting ViewSonic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determining the cause of display issues is generally a basic troubleshooting task, performing substitution on components until the faulty component is determined:

- replace cables (you've already done this)
- use the monitor on a different computer
- use a different monitor on the same computer

In this case, you've used a different monitor on the same machine and found that when using the same cables, the different monitor is not showing the color changes, therefore the monitor has the issue.

Comment: Yep, I got in contact with ViewSonic support and they sent me a new monitor.  Just set the new one up and problem solved.
So, just a faulty monitor.